# vba code to open myscript.js through notepad, and replace specific texts inside by the value from spreadsheet

Tags: vba, shell

I want open myscript.js through notepad, and replace the specific texts inside by the values from worksheet. For example, inside myscript.js I have 6:7.400, 12:6.500, 24:7.000. I want to replace these 3 texts by the values from worksheet "Sheet1" range D2 to D4, say '6:7.100', '12:6.000', '24:7.200' without changes the format inside myscript.js. After replacement, I want to save myscript.js

I just tried open myscript.js through notepad, but no idea how to change the texts inside and how to save myscript.js,

```
Sub js()


    Dim pth As String
    
    pth = "K:\MVS\temp\myscript.js"

    Shell "Notepad.exe " & pth, vbNormalFocus
    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA can read/write text file w/o other library.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceTextInFile()
    Dim srcFPath As String
    Dim desFPath As String
    Dim FileContent As String
    Dim NewContent As String
    Dim FileNumber As Integer
    Dim des_txt, src_txt, i As Integer
    src_txt = Array("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")
    des_txt = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D4").Value
    srcFPath = "D:\temp\template.js" ' update as needed
    desFPath = "D:\temp\myscript.js" ' update as needed
    If Dir(srcFPath) = "" Then
        MsgBox "File is not exists:" & srcFPath, vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Read js file
    FileNumber = FreeFile
    Open srcFPath For Input As FileNumber
    Do Until EOF(FileNumber)
        Line Input #FileNumber, FileContent
        NewContent = NewContent & FileContent & vbCrLf
    Loop
    ' Replace the content
    For i = 1 To UBound(des_txt)
        NewContent = Replace(NewContent, src_txt(i - 1), des_txt(i, 1))
    Next
    ' Update js file
    Close FileNumber
    FileNumber = FreeFile
    Open desFPath For Output As FileNumber
    Print #FileNumber, NewContent
    Close FileNumber
End Sub
```

***template.js*** (AAA,BBB,CCC are placeholders for replacing)

```js
console.log('AAA')
function test(c) {
  assert(c.constructor === Child)
console.log('BBB')
}
console.log('CCC')
```

---

Update

> Question: Can you modify the codes a little bit further? Basically those Array #s inside myscript.js are from Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E4").

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceTextInFile()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileContent As String
    Dim NewContent As String
    Dim FileNumber As Integer
    Dim arr_txt, i As Integer
    arr_txt = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:E4").Value
    FilePath = "D:\temp\myscript.js"
    If Dir(FilePath) = "" Then
        MsgBox "File is not exists:" & FilePath, vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Read js file
    FileNumber = FreeFile
    Open FilePath For Input As FileNumber
    Do Until EOF(FileNumber)
        Line Input #FileNumber, FileContent
        NewContent = NewContent & FileContent & vbCrLf
    Loop
    ' Replace the content
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr_txt)
        NewContent = Replace(NewContent, arr_txt(i,2), arr_txt(i,1))
    Next
    ' Update js file
    Close FileNumber
    FileNumber = FreeFile
    Open FilePath For Output As FileNumber
    Print #FileNumber, NewContent
    Close FileNumber
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, this code works amazing. Can you modify the codes a little bit further? Basically those Array #s inside myscript.js are from Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E4"). Each time I need to move the values from range(D2:D4) to range(E2:E4), and input the new values into range(D2:D4), and get myscript.js updated with new values from range(D2:D4)

Comment: I have upated the code.

Comment: Thanks again. The 2nd codes above run without errors, however, the values in range E2: E4 are not replaced by values from range D2:D4, and the values from range D2:D4 are not written into myscipt.js. I tried to modify your codes, but since I am pretty new to VB language I always get error messages after my modifications. so since I don't care about the values in range E2:E4, and I just need to write the values in range D2:D4 into myscrip.js, I am wondering if we can remove the Replace function, and directly write the values in range D2:D4 into myscript.js?

Comment: Please double check the value of E2:E4, it might be different with your input. Excel think it is a timestamp if you input `6:7.400` in a cell. It is mismached with your js. The cell value will be `0:06:07`. Try to input `'6:7.400` (starts with an single quotation marker) and run the code again.

Comment: I am pretty sure I input the correct format for 6:7.400. If I use the 1st codes, and manually insert the #s into src_txt = Array("6:7.400", "12:6.500", "24:7.000"), and then change the values in range D2:D4 for exmple, 6:1.000, 12:2.000, 24:3.000, and run it. my .js files will be updated with new values. but the 2nd codes neither update the value in .js nor change the values in range E2:E4.

Comment: Both snippets have same replacement logic. The only difference is src_txt. If D2:D4 is correctly read by code, it is no way to mess up E2:E4.

Comment: I agree with you. The only difference is src_txt, but the truth is the values in .js are not updated with values from D2:D4. I made some changes in 1st codes that I replace #s in Array by range("E2").... for example, and it looks it works. Anyway, appreciate your inputs and efforts. You help me a lot

Comment: Add `Debug.Print arr_txt(i, 2), arr_txt(i, 1)` before replace to validate the text before replacing. Or check it in debugging.

Comment: I did added test by entering Debug.Print arr_txt(i, 2), arr_txt(i, 1), and debug.print NewContent. The Debug.Print arr_txt(i, 2), arr_txt(i, 1) lists all the values from D2:E4 in order D2, E2, D3, E3, D4, E4, but it looks the 'Replace' function' doesn't work because the values in E2:E4 in my worksheet 'Sheet1' do not change. Also, debug.print NewContent still shows the original values instead of values from D2:D4

Comment: `the values in E2:E4 in my worksheet 'Sheet1' do not change` May I know what's the expected change?

Comment: The values in range D2:D4 represent the new values, and E2:E4 represent the old values. Basically what I want my codes to do is replacing old values by new values in .js. For example, if my current D2 value is 6:7.000 and E2 value is 6:5.900, and the when I update the value in D2 (through formula or other macros) to 6:7.100, and implement the codes, the value in E2 becomes 6:7.000 (original D2 value), and NewContent becomes 6:7.100 (new D2 value). and this 6:7.100 will be written into .js

Comment: `implement the codes, the value in E2 becomes 6:7.000 (original D2 value)` This is the fist time to see that updating Ex is needed. The code doesn't cover it. The more important thing is how to get the original D2.

Comment: My purpose is replacing the values in .js by the values in range D2:D4. The value format in .js is 6:7.000, 12:6.000, 24:5.000, but these values in .js will be written by the values in range D2:D4 when there are changes in value in range D2:D4 and when I implement the codes. The values in range D2:D4 are obtained from other sources.

Comment: Using D2:D4 for replacement is straightforward. The key challenge lies in guiding the code to identify the keywords to be replaced with Dx. The underlying issue causing the failure in the second code is that E2:E2 does not match keywords in the JavaScript file. To address this, I recommend including placeholders in the JS template, such as AA, BB, and CC (corresponding to E2:E4). The code can then replace these placeholders with new values from D2:D4 and save the result as a new JSt file. This approach eliminates the need to worry about updating E2:E4.

Comment: Thanks for your advise but I have no idea how to modify the codes with placeholder added in. Actually we don't need to care about the values in range E2:E4. What I want is just writing values in range D2:D4 to .js. My initial thought is how the codes know which values in .js I want to rewrite, so I let the codes find the values in .js and replace by new values in range D2:D4. That would be easier if we can directly write the values in range D2:D4 to .js

Comment: Please have a look on the 1st code snippet. It was revised to show the solution with placeholders.

Comment: Thanks for your updates. I know some simple VB terminologies and logic, but nothing for java script. I believe the updated codes in code 1 makes the things more complicated for me. I revised and tested original code 1, and it works. The changes I did is I replace Array("6:7.000", "12:6.000", "24:5.000") by Array(Sheets("Sheet1").range("E2")......)

Comment: Clicked. Really appreciate your inputs and efforts. It helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `FileSystemObject` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object)

The `FileSystemObject` is useful when you are directly working with files and folders. It also has methods that allow you to open Textfiles and read/write their content. I'd start trying `OpenAsTextStream` `OpenTextFile` `WriteLine` (JS files should work, since they are basically text files - but since I haven't used them with VBA before I can't say for certain)